# Problema con Mongo db?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongod

estoy creando un backend para una practica y cuando abro mongod.exe me aparece esto en mi consola

```
    {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.785-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.788-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.789-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.790-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":12848,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-SJC9RSI"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.790-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.790-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.790-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 18363)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.790-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.792-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.793-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=1477M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.827-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599287560:827074][12848:140707632602704], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 11 through 12"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:40.952-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599287560:952743][12848:140707632602704], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 12 through 12"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.073-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599287561:73413][12848:140707632602704], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 11/23680 to 12/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.228-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599287561:228002][12848:140707632602704], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 11 through 12"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.350-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599287561:350287][12848:140707632602704], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 12 through 12"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.429-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599287561:429074][12848:140707632602704], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.463-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":670}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.463-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.470-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.473-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.474-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:41.481-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:42.113-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":23718,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC","attr":{"error":{"code":179,"codeName":"WindowsPdhError","errmsg":"PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'El objeto especificado no se encontró en el equipo.' for counter '\\Processor(_Total)\\% Idle Time'"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:42.114-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:42.120-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T01:32:42.120-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

Soy nuevo con mongo, alguien sabe  si es problema por una mala instalación? o algo con Node.js?
Gracias a todos de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: lo que estas haciendo al ejecutar ´mongod.exe´ es ejecutar un ´servidor´ de mongodb, lo que te esta indicando la consola es que esta esperando por conexiones, tu base de datos se esta ejecutando con normalidad y lista para ser usada